# Click two links respectively in one URL by python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

This is my very first post, so if there are any mistakes please accept my apologies.

First of all, I am really very new to python. My question may be silly but I have tried to search many sources, but there was no answer for me.

What I would like to do is click two links subsequently in just the same URL. In other words, the second link will show up after the first link is being clicked.

The code ran well, but it did not click on the second link. Any suggestions are very welcome. Thank you

Here what I have tried:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/Kob/Desktop/Python projects/Chrome webdriver/Chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("http://www2.ops3.moc.go.th/")

Export = driver.find_element_by_link_text("EXPORT")
Export.click()

driver.implicitly_wait(10)

Yearly = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Yearly")
Yearly.click()
```

and this is an occurred error message

```js
runfile('C:/Users/Kob/Desktop/Python projects/MOC_spyder project/web driver.py', wdir='C:/Users/Kob/Desktop/Python projects/MOC_spyder project')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-12-05875762a23a>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Kob/Desktop/Python projects/MOC_spyder project/web driver.py', wdir='C:/Users/Kob/Desktop/Python projects/MOC_spyder project')

  File "c:\users\kob\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "c:\users\kob\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Kob/Desktop/Python projects/MOC_spyder project/web driver.py", line 19, in <module>
    Yearly.click()

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'click'
```

Comment: Export and Yearly links are on the same page?

Comment: did you get an error message when it failed to click on the second link?  if so, please show us the stack trace.

Comment: You need to handle the popups first. The invoke click on `Yearly`

Comment: @SadiaArif Thank for your prompt response and Yes, it is located on the same page, but I need to click on the export first before "Yearly" link show up.

Comment: @DebanjanB Thank for your prompt response. Below is an error message I got.

  File "C:/Users/Kob/Desktop/Python projects/MOC_spyder project/web driver.py", line 19, in <module>
    Yearly.click()

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'click'

Comment: @DebanjanB Thank you for your suggestion. This means that I need to close both of popups first, am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click on the Link Yearly you have to switch to the IFrame "data" where this link is located.

So before locating the link "Yearly" add this statement:

```
driver.switch_to.frame("data")
```

The complete code which I tested and works:

```
driver.get("http://www2.ops3.moc.go.th/")

main_window = driver.window_handles[0]
new_window1 = driver.window_handles[1]
new_window2 = driver.window_handles[2]

driver.switch_to.window(new_window1)
driver.close()
driver.switch_to.window(new_window2)
driver.close()
driver.switch_to.window(main_window)

Export = driver.find_element_by_link_text("EXPORT")
Export.click()
driver.switch_to.frame("data")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
Yearly = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Yearly")
Yearly.click()
```

Comment: Hi Frank, Thank you for your suggestion, but I still got a bug with this solution. Below is an error message that I got.


  File "c:\users\kob\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Yearly."}
  (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.181)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.37.544315 (730aa6a5fdba159ac9f4c1e8cbc59bf1b5ce12b7),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64)

Any suggestion?

Comment: Hi Kob, it was more then a suggestion, I tested the code and it worked for me, I added all my code to the answer. If this still not works for you, let me know then it is possibly a matter of timing. Also let me know if you need some explanation.

Comment: Thank you Frank, it is working!. You have just saved python novice like me. Would you mind explaining me why my code does not work? Is it probably because of popup windows?

Thank you again Frank, really appreciated your kind help :)

Comment: I'm wondering why, in your original code, you succeeded to click on the first link but not on the second. Are you sure about that? After navigating to the URL immediately two windows are opening which have to be closed before you can interact with the maine frame. That's what the code about which is executed before the click on the first link.

Comment: Sorry for late reply and yes, I am sure that I could succeed to click the first link but not the second one. However, your code could solve this problem. Thank you very much :). Next, I will try to handle with the drop-down list. Could I bother you again if I have anymore questions about using the selenium?

Comment: Sure, no problem.